# Generalization of multinomial theorem for powers of multinomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am trying to estimate the following expectation value in the multinomial probability distribution:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{P}\left[ \left( \frac{n!}{x_1!..x_k!}\right)^{\alpha - 1} \right]
\end{equation}

where $P$ the usual multinomial distribution, $\theta_i \in [0,1] \forall i$, $\sum_{i=1}^{k} \theta_i = 1$, $\alpha \in (0,+\infty)\setminus \{1\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = n$.

1) Thus, I am wondering if there exists an extension of the multinomial theorem for the following:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{x_1 + .. + x_k = n} \left( \frac{n!}{x_1!..x_k!}\right)^{\alpha} \theta_1^{x_1}..\theta_k^{x_k}
\end{equation}

2) If not, would there be a way to estimate this w/o using Stirling on the $x_i$?

I found asymptotic estimates of the sum of powers of multinomial coefficients in my search (https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.5028), however this does not seem very useful here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there exists an closed-form expression for 
\begin{equation}
S_\alpha := \sum_{x_1 + .. + x_k = n} \left( \frac{n!}{x_1!..x_k!}\right)^{\alpha} \theta_1^{x_1}..\theta_k^{x_k}.
\end{equation}
Using the [power mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality), it can be bounded as follows:
$$S_\alpha \lessgtr \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}^{1-\alpha}(\theta_1^{1/\alpha}+\cdots+ \theta_k^{1/\alpha})^{n\alpha},$$
where the sign is $\geq$ when $\alpha>1$, and $\leq$ otherwise.

Comment: Dear Max, Thanks for your reply. Could you maybe elaborate a bit on how you found this bound using the power mean inequality?

Comment: Just interpret $\left(\frac{S_\alpha}{\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}}\right)^{1/\alpha}$ as the $\alpha$-th power mean of the terms $\frac{n!}{x_1!\cdots x_k!} \theta_1^{x_1/\alpha}\cdots \theta_k^{x_k/\alpha}$, and compare it to the 1-st power mean of these terms.

Comment: Okay I got it. Then you use the multinomial theorem on the 1-st power means and resolve for $S_{\alpha}$. Thank you very much for your help